# How can I sync Xubuntu's calendar Orage with Google Calendar?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, 15.10, google, calendar

Does anyone know how to sync Xubuntu 15.10 calendar (Orage) with Google Calendar? I found some old links but it doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: Is one-way sync sufficient? This looks fairly straightforward. http://dontsurfinthenude.blogspot.com/2013/08/sync-orage-and-google-calendar.html

Answer (score 1):

There is [an interesting article here](https://aymanbagabas.com/2018/04/08/sync-google-calendar.html) (8 april 2018 by Ayman Bagabas) that suggests using a utility, [Vdirsyncer](https://vdirsyncer.pimutils.org/en/stable/index.html), to perform the synchronisation. vdirsyncer is a command line tool that can synchronise calendars and address books between servers and the local file system in both directions. Typically, it is run periodically through `cron` or a `systemd` service.

Setup is not quite straightforward, and requires some technical experience. Details are [outlined in the article](https://aymanbagabas.com/2018/04/08/sync-google-calendar.html).

1. Using a configuration file, the synchronization is set up with respect to vdirsyncer.
2. One needs to enable the CALDAV API for the Google account from within the [Google API console](https://console.developers.google.com/).
3. Then `vdirsyncer` needs to be granted access to the Google account.
4. Orage must be pointed to the synchronized file
5. With `cron` or `systemd`, `vdirsyncer` is run periodically.

In case the article is not available in the future, some information is replicated here. Credit goes to Ayman Bagabas, the author of the article:

**Prerequisites**

Have vdirsyncer and orage installed:

```
sudo apt install vdirsyncer orage
```

**1. Configuration file**

An example of a configuration file `~/.vdirsyncer/status` for `vdirsyncer` is given as:

```
[general]
status_path = "~/.vdirsyncer/status/"

[pair calendar]
a = "google_calendar"
b = "local_calendar"
collections = ["from a", "from b"]
metadata = ["color"]

[storage local_calendar]
type = "singlefile"
path = "~/.calendars/%s.ics"

[storage google_calendar]
type = "google_calendar"
token_file = "~/.vdirsyncer/google_token"
client_id = "CLIENT_ID"
client_secret = "CLIENT_SECRET"
```

**2. Enable CALDAV API for your google account**

1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and create a new project.
2. Click on “Enable APIs and Services” or on the left side click on Library, then search for “CalDAV” and enable it.
3. Click on “create credentials” then choose “CalDAV API” for your API and select “Other” for Application type. Click next and choose a name e.g. “vdirsyncer” then click continue.
4. You will get your client id, stick it into your configuration file.
5. Click "done" after you get the client id then click on the credentials name and get the client secret from there.

**3. Grant `vdirsyncer` access to your Google account**

`$ vdirsyncer discover calendar`

This will authorize the pair calendar provided in the config file. A browser window will pop up to complete the authorization with google.

**4. Point Orage to the synchronised file**

In Orage: File -> Exchange data, and add the files under `~/.calendars` (according to the example config file above).

Syncronisation should now work, and can be done with the command

`vdirsyncer sync`

Remains to have that command periodically run (e.g. every hour) using `cron` or `systemd`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can modify this file /home/user/.config/orage/oragerc approximately like that:

```
Archive file=/home/user/Dropbox/orage/orage_archive.ics
Orage file=/home/user/Dropbox/orage/orage.ics
```

These files are (or should be) originally in /home/user/.local/share/orage (2)

Or you can go in Orage to File -> Share data (or data share?(1)) to change the paths of the files.

So, you could sync with any computer or mobile with Orage (but not Google Calendar) and your Dropbox account. However, I have not tried yet but it works with passwords manager like Keepass.

In any case, synchronizing an application with a Google app requires lowering the security of the Google app.

Do you know? "Orages" means "thunderstorm" in French.

*(1)Échanger des données in the french version*
*(2) If you never used Orage, they will not exist yet*